# how to run a function on boolean value change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run a the function check() when run is 1 and only then,
the problem I have is that the check() function scrolls left and this runs the function again,

How can I create a boolean and flip it whiteout the function check runs all the time?

I'm sorry about the explanation it's my first question, Thankful for all help!!

```
$( "#element" ).scrollstop(function() {
   run = 0
   check()
}); 

function check(){
    console.log(run)
    if(run === 1){
       $('#element').animate({
        scrollLeft: '10px'
       })
       run=0
     }
  }
```

Comment: Try `if (run==1){check()}` in your scrollstop function

Comment: If you set `run = 0` before calling `check` when can `run===1` ever be true in `check`?

Comment: ``run = 0`` and  ``check()`` and ``if(run === 1)`` always ``false``.

Comment: You could create a function where you set `run` then perform additional logic i.e. `function setRun(x) { run = x; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

`run` is not visible to `check()`. You should pass it as an argument:

```
$( "#element" ).scrollstop(function() {
   var run = 0;
   check(run);
}); 

function check(run){
    console.log(run);
    if(run === 1){
       $('#element').animate({
        scrollLeft: '10px';
       });
     }
  }
```

But then you can't revert `run`to 0 in `check()`, you'll have to do that elsewhere.

Also you're missing semicolons. I added them to the code.

I suggest you read some tutorials on javascript scope, for example this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

I've declared the `run` variable globally and changed the value to boolean instead of integer so the code is more clear.

```
var run = false;

$("#element").scrollstop(function() {
   run = true; // this must be true before calling check()
   check();
}); 

function check(){
    console.log(run)
    if(run){
        run = false;
        $("#element").animate({
            scrollLeft: '10px'
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below,

```
var documentScroll = function() {
    $(document).animate({
         scrollLeft: '10px'
    }, function() {
        $(document).one('scroll', documentScroll);
    });
};

$(document).one('scroll', documentScroll);
```